# Modal not opening anymore

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I had this working a couple of days ago and now I am beating my head against a wall trying to figure why they are no longer opening.  I believe the code is clean , but I am obviously missing something.

Any help is appreciated.  Here is the code that I am using.

```
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' type='text/css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/Site.css" />

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center " style="align-content:center;">Matter Index </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptmanager1" />

            <!-- Move Client Modal -->


                    <div id="moveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server" >
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Move Matter</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fvclient" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must select a new client." CssClass="alert-danger col-md-12" ControlToValidate="ddMove" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgMove" />
                                  <label for="ddMove">New Client:</label> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddMove" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />                               
                              </div>                                                              
                             </div>
                           <div class="modal-footer">
                               <asp:Button ID="btnMove" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm col-md-1" OnClick="btnMove_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="vgMove"/>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>


        <!-- Delete Client Modal -->


                    <div id="delModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server" >
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Matter</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="delAlert">Are you sure you want to delete this matter?  This action is not reversible.</label>                               
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer" >
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm col-md-1" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                          </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
                <asp:FormView ID="fvdoc" runat="server" DataSourceID="gvdb" OnItemUpdated="fvdoc_ItemUpdated">
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#ccffff" Wrap="false" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h2 class="col-md-12"><asp:Label runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("docid") %> id="a"/> - <asp:Label runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("sName") %> id="b"/></h2>

                                <div class="left col-md-10"> 
                                    <legend>Matter Info:</legend>
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                           <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Matter" />
                                           <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=<%# Bind("sDocname") %> id="idocname"/>
                                       </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-10">
                                    <hr />
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Notes/Comments" />
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=<%# Bind("sdocdesc") %> id="c"/>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 txsmall"> 
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Filed: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="d" runat="server"  Text=<%# Bind("dtFiledate") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true" />
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Modified: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="e" runat="server" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dtLastModified") + " - " + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"susermodified") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true"/>                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear-fix col-md-12">
                                   <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" CommandName="Edit" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Move" ID="MoveButton" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveModal" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Delete" ID="DelButton" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delModal" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Home" ID="HomeButton" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" CausesValidation="False" href="default.aspx"/>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <h2 class="col-md-12"><asp:Label ID="lbldocid" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("docid") %> /> - <asp:Label ID="lblclient" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("sName") %> /></h2>

                                <div class="left col-md-10"> 
                                    <legend>Matter Info:</legend>
                                       <div class="form-group"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Matter" AssociatedControlID="dcname"/>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="dcname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text=<%# Bind("sDocname") %> /></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="left col-md-10">
                                    <hr />
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Notes/Comments" AssociatedControlID="dcnotes" /><br />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="dcnotes" runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" Text=<%# Bind("sdocdesc") %> />
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- 
                                <div class="left col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 txsmall"> 
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Filed: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblfiledate" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtFiledate") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Modified: " Font-Bold="true" /><asp:Label ID="lblmodify" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("dtLastModified") + " - " + Bind("susermodified") %> CssClass="txsmall" Font-Italic="true"/>                                   
                                </div> -->
                                <div class="clear-fix col-md-12">
                                   <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveButton" CommandName="Update" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" Enabled="true" />&nbsp;
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="clear-fix btn btn-info" />&nbsp;
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                </asp:FormView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" />
    </div>

 <...datasource ...>
</form>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  The issue was the placement of the `.js` files at the end of the body.  It apparently doesn't like that anymore.  I moved them back to the `<head>` and fully closed `</script>` not self closed `/>`.  Once I did that it started working just fine.